# Acid-state: MonadState instance for Update

Tags: haskell, ghc, acid-state

I'm trying `acid-state`. The [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/acid-state/0.6.4/doc/html/Data-Acid.html#t%3aUpdate) states that `Update st` is an instance of `MonadState st`. I tried different things, but my compiler doesn't want to see that :( I tried the `HelloWorld.hs` from [examples](http://mirror.seize.it/acid-state/examples/), but got the same issue:

```
HelloWorld.hs:26:7:
    No instance for (MonadState
                       HelloWorldState (Update HelloWorldState))
      arising from a use of `put'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (MonadState HelloWorldState (Update HelloWorldState))
    In the expression: put (HelloWorldState newValue)
    In an equation for `writeState':
        writeState newValue = put (HelloWorldState newValue)

HelloWorld.hs:29:43:
    No instance for (MonadReader
                       HelloWorldState (Query HelloWorldState))
      arising from a use of `ask'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (MonadReader HelloWorldState (Query HelloWorldState))
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: HelloWorldState string <- ask
    In the expression:
      do { HelloWorldState string <- ask;
           return string }
    In an equation for `queryState':
        queryState
          = do { HelloWorldState string <- ask;
                 return string }
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to make it work?

I'm using
`acid-state-0.6.4`,
`ghc-7.4.2`,
`debian-6.0.5` (amd64)

Thanks,
Yuras

**ADDED:**
Looks like it works in ghc-7.4.1 and doesn't work in ghc-7.4.2. Could anybody both compilers?

I tried reinstalling acid-state, but it didn't help. Either a bug in ghc-7.4.2 or my environment id broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved it.

The issue was with two different `mtl` versions installed. Hiding the wrong one fixed everything.

The interesting part is how I got it :)

```
Prelude Data.Acid Control.Monad.State> :i Update
newtype Update st a
  = acid-state-0.6.4:Data.Acid.Common.Update {acid-state-0.6.4:Data.Acid.Common.unUpdate :: transformers-0.2.2.0:Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.State
                                                                                              st a}
    -- Defined in `acid-state-0.6.4:Data.Acid.Common'
instance Monad (Update st)
  -- Defined in `acid-state-0.6.4:Data.Acid.Common'
instance Functor (Update st)
  -- Defined in `acid-state-0.6.4:Data.Acid.Common'
Prelude Data.Acid Control.Monad.State>
```

`Control.Monad.State` reexports `State`, but you can see that ghci still shows `transformers-0.2.2.0:Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy.State` fully qualified.