# Haskell HTTP client using ByteString

Tags: string, http, haskell, bytestring

I'm doing some HTTP Requests and I want to get the corresponding Responses as ByteString instead of String. I'm using [HTTP-4000.2.18](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.18).

As far as I can tell, this is precisely what [BufferType](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.18/docs/Network-BufferType.html) is for:

> to give the user freedom in how request and response content is represented

However, I'm at a loss on how to make it work. Here's what I have so far: I'm constructing requests using a function called `getLazyRequest` as follows:

```
getLazyRequest
    :: String                   -- ^URL to fetch
    -> Request Lazy.ByteString  -- ^The constructed request
```

and then I should be able to pass the requests directly to [simpleHTTP](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.18/docs/Network-HTTP.html#v:simpleHTTP).
The getLazyRequest function is identical with [getRequest](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.18/docs/Network-HTTP.html#v:getRequest) except it returns a request with type ByteString instead of String. But it doesn't work..

Complete source:

```
import Network.HTTP
import Network.URI ( parseURI )
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as Lazy
import Network.BufferType ( BufferOp(..), BufferType(..) )


main = do
    let req = getLazyRequest "http://hackage.haskell.org/"
    rsp <- simpleHTTP req
    line <- fmap (take 100) (getResponseBody rsp)
    putStrLn ""


getLazyRequest
    :: String                   -- ^URL to fetch
    -> Request Lazy.ByteString  -- ^The constructed request
getLazyRequest urlString =
  case parseURI urlString of
    Nothing -> error ("getLazyRequest: Not a valid URL - " ++ urlString)
    Just u  -> mkRequest GET u
```

The errors:

```
No instance for (HStream Lazy.ByteString)
  arising from a use of `simpleHTTP'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (HStream Lazy.ByteString)
In a stmt of a 'do' block: rsp <- simpleHTTP req

No instance for (BufferType Lazy.ByteString)
  arising from a use of `mkRequest'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (BufferType Lazy.ByteString)
In the expression: mkRequest GET u
In a case alternative: Just u -> mkRequest GET u
```

I don't understand why these errors, since Lazy.ByteString is an instance both of [HStream](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.18/docs/src/Network-TCP.html#HStream) and [BufferType](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.2.18/docs/src/Network-BufferType.html#BufferType).

**EDIT**

Indeed, I have to versions of bytestring installed. Is it possible that I installed one of them using sudo and the other using my user?

```
$ ghc-pkg list bytestring
/var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
   bytestring-0.9.2.1
/home/adizere/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.4.1/package.conf.d
   bytestring-0.10.4.1
```

I couldn't unregister any of these two versions, so instead I cabalized the code and it seems to work now.

Comment: probably multiple `bytestring` packages installed? what `ghc-pkg list bytestring` outputs?

Comment: Indeed, I had two versions of bytestring installed. I'm editing my question to complete the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since @user5402 confirmed that your code is correct (modulo `take` vs `Lazy.take`), then I'm almost sure you have multiple versions of `bytestring` package installed. E.g. you are importing one version, but `HTTP` is compiled against other one.

Check `ghc-pkg list bytestring` and unregister/hide one unnecessary version.

Or, better, cabalize your code and/or use cabal sandbox.

See also:
[Acid-state: MonadState instance for Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068272/acid-state-monadstate-instance-for-update)
and
https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8278#comment:2

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
    line <- fmap (take 100) (getResponseBody rsp)
```

to:

```
    line <- fmap (Lazy.take 100) (getResponseBody rsp)
```

Your code type-checks on my system with this change.