# How has instance (Param B.ByteString) managed to vanish?

Tags: mysql, haskell, cabal

I have some old code which used to compile, but now it doesn't. I worry I may have hit a package management snafu, and I'm really bad at dealing with that sort of thing. I've cut it down to a minimal failing example.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Gremlin where

import Database.MySQL.Simple.Param
import qualified Data.ByteString as SB

foo :: Param x => [x]
foo = []

shoo :: [SB.ByteString]
shoo = foo
```

The error I get is

```
/.../Gremlin.hs:12:8:
No instance for (Param SB.ByteString) arising from a use of ‘foo’
In the expression: foo
In an equation for ‘shoo’: shoo = foo
```

But when I look at the source code for

```
module Database.MySQL.Simple.Param
    (
      Action(..)
    , Param(..)
    , inQuotes
    ) where
```

I see

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as SB
```

and

```
instance Param SB.ByteString where
    render = Escape
    {-# INLINE render #-}
```

Relevant version information may include

```
$ ghci --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.2
$ ghc-pkg latest mysql-simple
mysql-simple-0.2.2.5
$ ghc-pkg latest bytestring
bytestring-0.10.8.1
```

When I ask ghci

```
:info Param
```

I get a shorter list than the mysql-simple documentation would lead me to expect.

```
Prelude> :m + Database.MySQL.Simple.Param Data.ByteString
Prelude Database.MySQL.Simple.Param Data.ByteString> :info Param
class Param a where
  render :: a -> Action  
    -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
instance Param [Char] -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
instance Param Word -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
instance Param a => Param (Maybe a)
  -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
instance Param Integer -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
instance Param Int -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
instance Param Float -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
instance Param Double -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
instance Param Bool -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
instance Param Action -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
```

but I suppose that only tells me the instances for what's locally in scope. I then do

```
Prelude Database.MySQL.Simple.Param Data.ByteString> :m +Data.Text
Prelude Database.MySQL.Simple.Param Data.ByteString Data.Text> :info Param
class Param a where
...
instance Param Text -- Defined in ‘Database.MySQL.Simple.Param’
...
```

Further investigation points to a potential source of trouble:

```
$ ghc-pkg describe mysql-simple
name: mysql-simple
version: 0.2.2.5
...
depends:
...
    bytestring-0.10.6.0-6e8453cb70b477776f26900f41a5e17a
...
```

I'm guessing that the `ByteString` with the instance is from `0.10.6.0` and distinct from the version I get when write exactly the same import in my source file. If so, I'm a bit peeved at how much work I had to do to find that out: it would be great if "No instance for Foo" would add "even though there's an instance for a whole other Foo".

This is cabal hell, right? Can I make mysql-simple rebuild with the newer version? I tried `ghc-pkg unregister mysql-simple` and then `cabal install mysql-simple`, but to no avail.

What's a good repair strategy?

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code in a clean cabal sandbox?

Comment: I'm no expert in why these things happen, but I usually list the package I want and the problematic package with the specific version I need.  So `cabal install mysql-simple bytestring-0.10.8.1`.  This usually either works or gives me a better reason why it won't work.

Comment: @redneb I didn't use a sandbox, but I did have to install mysql-simple and utf8-bytestring. And I did it in that order. I think there may have been an old bytestring there already, but that utf8-bytestring might have brought in the new one, like a no warning disaster.

Comment: @fryguybob I just tried that. Hilariously it did a lot more thinking than I expected and decided to do a version bump to pcre-light-0.4.0.4, whose config stage failed because pkg-config could not be found. I don't blame you, ok?

Comment: @fryguybob and indeed, a brew install pkg-config later, all was well. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> What's a good repair strategy?

I urge you to cabalize the code and use cabal sandbox or `stack`. It should prevent the issue in the first place. To repair, you should find out what package is installed twice (it seems to be `bytestring`) and unregister it.

> I'm a bit peeved at how much work I had to do to find that out: it would be great if "No instance for Foo" would add "even though there's an instance for a whole other Foo".

I [know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068272/acid-state-monadstate-instance-for-update) what you feel. Fortunately it is already [fixed](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9611), so you should get better error message from `ghc-8`

Comment: Great! I look forward to upgrading to ghc 8, which I will do as soon as this fix https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/12007 makes it out there. Demanding simultaneous cabal install of mysql-simple and the newer bytestring got me out of the hole. Cabalizing my rather small only-one-local-special-purpose program would add considerable overhead.