# Acid-State example compiled error. No No instance for (Control.Monad.Reader.Class.MonadReader FailureDb (Query FailureDb))

Tags: haskell, nix, nixos

I was trying acid [example](https://gist.github.com/YuMingLiao/f451f7687a738a141de5d0008f1b9035) but compile error.

[The error message](https://gist.github.com/YuMingLiao/f451f7687a738a141de5d0008f1b9035#file-error) says `no instance No instance for MonadState, No instance for MonadReader`.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068272/acid-state-monadstate-instance-for-update/11072232#11072232) says it is due to two different mtl versions installed.

And I am using nix-shell in nixos:

```
ghc-pkg list | grep acid
    acid-state-0.14.3

ghc-pkg list | grep mtl
    mtl-2.2.1
    mtl-2.2.2
```

However, if I don't use acid-state package when I enter nix-shell, I got:

```
ghc-pkg list | grep mtl
    mtl-2.2.2
```

That probably means acid-state is using different mtl version than Control.Monad.Reader.

But acid-state's stack.yaml in github is lts-11.15, which has mtl-2.2.2.

So what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Okay, I `ghc-pkg unregister --force mtl-2.2.2` and the example works! But I haven't solved the mystery of why nix-shell install acid-state with mtl-2.2.1 instead of 2.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack and Cabal-install have similar problems when dealing with GHC's package dbs, but these problems can be avoided:

### Stack

When I use Stack, I don't run it in a nix-shell, so that the nix-shell can't add packages to the wrapped GHC command that Stack will then consider to be system packages ('global' in Cabal terminology). I am not sure whether this is the only valid approach though.

### Cabal-install only

When calling Cabal in a nix-shell, you should add these flags to prevent GHC from looking at the wrong package db: `cabal configure --package-db=clear --package-db=global`. The GHC wrapper will make the Nix-managed dependencies appear in the 'global' package db.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out there are different existing packages. The Stack way works for me.