# Can I replicate what nix-build does with nix-shell and cabal build?

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, nix

I'm using the splendid Haskell library [Miso](https://github.com/dmjio/miso), which recommends using Nix. The README walks us through a simple project which can be built with `nix-build`. The documentation for Miso hints that I can do:

```
nix-shell -A env
cabal configure --ghcjs
cabal build
```

which also builds the project, although it places the result in a different place.

Are `nix-build` and `cabal build` within nix-shell guaranteed to produce the same output? More generally, given a `.nix` expression how would I workout what steps (such as cabal configure) are required to replicate it's behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you are not guaranteed that the output of `nix-build` and the same steps in a `nix-shell` will equivalent. Some causes of differences:

- `nix-build` can run the build in a sandbox, whereas `nix-shell` will not.
- `nix-shell` can be invoked without the `--pure` flag, so that many more environment variables will be set (this lets you use GUI applications for example)
- Although `nix-shell` sets the `$out` environment variable, it is not writable
- A process in `nix-shell` runs as your user, whereas `nix-build` with the daemon enabled will typically run it as `nixbld<n>`, even with sandboxing disabled

And there's probably more I didn't think of right now.

For cabal-install and plain `ghc` in particular, a consequence of running without the sandbox is that it can access your user package db. This requires some care when using these tools in a `nix-shell`; [see this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52108291/acid-state-example-compiled-error-no-no-instance-for-control-monad-reader-clas/52111765#52111765)